# Loop over Shapes but not Comments

Tags: excel, vba

I have a huge Excel file, that I have to evaluate. I'm trying to automate this task. The Excel file contains a lot of shapes (text boxes) and comments. I need to evaluate the text boxes but to ignore the comments. Apparently when I loop over shapes with a for each loop, I also get the comments. Is there a way to ignore the comments. Here is my code:

```
    For Each shp In ActiveSheet.Shapes
        On Error GoTo NextShape
        If InStr(shp.Name, ", ") Then
            splitName = Split(shp.Name, ", ")
            If splitName(UBound(splitName)) = "FS" Then
                check_codes_in_Textbox shp
            End If
        End If
NextShape:
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then MsgBox (Err.Description)
    Next
```

In my Excel file a lot of the textboxes have ", FS" in their name, that is why I was trying to use an InStr-Function, but this way is kind of inconvenient.

Is there a way to loop over shapes and not over comments?

Comment: I'm not getting your `On Error` statement. Why is that included? What am I missing here? Either way the [`msoShapeType`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/office.msoshapetype) of a TextBox is 17. So you could test like `If shp.Type = 17 Then`...

Comment: @JvdV well they are included in my loop. Maybe it is an issue with the Excel file or the way the comments are added, can't really tell because I didn't create the file. I added the `On Error` statement, because some of the shapes had their properties as "Application or object defined error". That would be my next question actually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use shp.Type

```
For Each shp In ActiveSheet.Shapes
    On Error GoTo NextShape
    If InStr(shp.Name, ", ") And shp.Type <> 4 Then 'type 4 is commment, type 17 is text box for example etc... Check with debug.print shp.Type what is current shape type
        splitName = Split(shp.Name, ", ")
        If splitName(UBound(splitName)) = "FS" Then
            check_codes_in_Textbox shp
        End If
    End If
NextShape:
If Err.Number <> 0 Then MsgBox (Err.Description)
Next
```

Comment: Thank you JvdV for editing. I was in rush so I didnt notice bad formatting.

Comment: use "shp.Type <> MsoShapeType.msoComment" instead of the "magic number 4"  to make your code more readable. :)